# Can't run ionic project from ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04

When I run the command
               sudo ionic cordova run android 
I got this error

```
Error: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
```

Although  I set JAVA_HOME

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then `source` that file with `source ~/.bashrc` or **close that terminal and reopen** then try your code again.

Comment: I did that and also the same error,
But the command sudo source ~/.bashrc ----
the output is : command not found so I close the terminal and reopen it

Comment: Replace `source` with a `.` so the command would be: `. ~/.bashrc` and see what happens and do **not** specify `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your `.bashrc` file in your home directory, close and reopen any terminal windows you have open and try again:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
```

Comment: I did that and also the same error appeared. :(